# How can you unify multiple encodings into one?

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8, web-scraping, utf-16

I would like to encode with utf-8.

However, there are 7 kinds of guess_encoding ().

Should I do this all with utf-8?

```
>guess_encoding(text)
  encoding language confidence
1    UTF-8                0.15

>guess_encoding(text)
  encoding language confidence
1        UTF-8                1.00
2     UTF-16BE                0.10
3     UTF-16LE                0.10
4 windows-1255       he       0.07
5 windows-1255       he       0.06
6   IBM420_ltr       ar       0.04
7   IBM420_rtl       ar       0.02
```

Does the meaning of "guess_encoding()" indicate how the encoding is structured?

Can not encode with "repair_encoding" code?

I have encoded this code but it does not seem to be working properly. Should I use "iconv"?

Do I have to encode this 6 times?

```
iconv(text, from="UTF-16BE", to="UTF8") 
iconv(text, from="UTF-16LE", to="UTF8")
iconv(text, from="windows-1255", to="UTF8") 
#Omitted below
```

The entire code is posted as a reference.

The contents of the question can be hard to understand

I put the whole code snugly.

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)


# Bulletin URL
list.url = 'http://kin.naver.com/qna/list.nhn?m=expertAnswer&dirId=70111'

# Vector to store title and body
text = c() #Answer the question

#  1 to 10 page bulletin crawling
for(i in 1:10){
  url = modify_url(list.url, query=list(page=i))  # Change the page in the bulletin URL
  h.list = read_html(url, encoding = 'UTF-8')  # Get a list of posts, read and save html files from url

  # Post link extraction
  title.link1 = html_nodes(h.list, '.title') #class of title
  title.links = html_nodes(title.link1, 'a') #title.link1 to a

  article.links = html_attr(title.links, 'href') 
  article.links = paste0("http://kin.naver.com",article.links) 

  #Extract attrribute
  for(link in article.links){
    h = read_html(link)  # Get the post

    # answer    
    text = html_text(html_nodes(h, '#contents_layer_1'))
    text= str_trim(repair_encoding(texts))
    texts=c(texts,text)

    print(link)

  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried `enc2utf8` ? and if so, what is wrong with the result ?

Comment: also please mention the library you're using, `guess_encoding` exists in several packages, at least in `rvest` and `readr`, it seems you're using `rvest`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper 
I do not understand what you mean, but I use "rvest".
Do you mean to change "h.list = read_html(url, encoding = 'UTF-8')" to "h.list = read_html(url, encoding = 'enc2utf8')"  like this?
 

When I do this, I get the same error I got above (= warning message).

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper My code is briefly a question and answer site like "stackoverflow". After entering the keyword, each URL of the question is to get the desired element.
 
In my entire code, I turned to title, content, and anss, but there was a problem in the anss section. So, do you have to change coding only in the anss section?

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper And thanks for the answer.
Thanks for not responding to this article. If you have a chance, I would like to send you a more detailed email. If you do not mind, can I get an e-mail address?

Comment: I was suggesting that you try `text <- enc2utf8(text)`. I don't have the permissions on my server to download files so I can't reproduce your code and help further.